# WordPress plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a custom version of WordPress and now I'm stucked with the plugins api...
Is there someone who can explain me how it works.
Thank you.

Comment: You'd get better answers on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and even better answers if you are more specific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this guide on [writing your first plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). Other than that, you should poke around existing plugins and see if you can follow all the API calls [described here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).

If you want more specific answers you should first start trying to develop something simple and come back when you hit a specific roadblock.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the [**Developer Documentation**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation) of Wordpress, that's how everybody learns how to create plugins.